# I can't register a user on ejabberd with postgresql

Tags: postgresql, xmpp, ejabberd

Whenever I try adding a new user like:

```
ejabberdctl register admin localhost default
```

It gives me the following error:

```
Problem 'error undef' occurred executing the command.
Stacktrace: [{ejabberd_odbc,escape,["admin"]},
         {ejabberd_auth_odbc,is_user_exists,2},
         {ejabberd_auth,'-is_user_exists/2-fun-0-',3},
         {lists,any,2},
         {ejabberd_auth,try_register,3},
         {ejabberd_admin,register,3},
         {ejabberd_ctl,call_command,3},
         {ejabberd_ctl,try_call_command,3}]
```

I have erlang with pg library, and set the following configurations on ejabberd:

```
{auth_method, odbc}.
{odbc_server, {pgsql, "localhost", "ejabberd", "root", "admin"}}.
```

I also created a database named ejabberd and migrated the pg.sql file. Do I need something else or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: have you checked postgres's logs? is `root` allowed to log in?

Comment: yes it is, because I've been using postgres for other apps too.